# how to CSS grid last size

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<div class="grid-layout">
    <img class="grid-item unview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/9.png">
    <img class="grid-item unview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/2.png">
    <img class="grid-item unview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/3.png">
    <img class="grid-item unview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/1.png">
    <img class="grid-item unview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/4.png">
    <img class="grid-item unview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/5.png">
    <img class="grid-item unview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/7.png">
    <img class="grid-item unview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/8.png">
    <img class="grid-item unview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/6.png">
    
    <img class="grid-item unview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/9.png">
    <img class="grid-item unview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/2.png">
    <img class="grid-item unview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/3.png">
    <img class="grid-item unview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/1.png">
    <img class="grid-item unview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/4.png">
    <img class="grid-item unview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/5.png">
    <img class="grid-item unview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/7.png">
    <img class="grid-item unview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/8.png">
    <img class="grid-item unview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/6.png">
    <img class="grid-item unview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/9.png">
    <img class="grid-item unview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/2.png">
    <img class="grid-item unview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/3.png">
    <img class="grid-item unview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/1.png">
    <img class="grid-item unview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/4.png">
    <img class="grid-item unview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/5.png">
    <img class="grid-item unview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/7.png">
    <img class="grid-item unview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/8.png">
    <img class="grid-item unview" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53819/6.png">
</div>
```

This is an html file.
Multiple images were inserted to create an image gallery.

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
}

.grid-layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(180px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(180px, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.span-2 {
  grid-column-end: span 2;
  grid-row-end: span 2;
  width: 100%;
}

.unview {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
          filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

This is a css file.
I found out that there was a grid structure, so I made it using the default code.
It was implemented as an unview to give a black-and-white effect.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".grid-item").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).addClass("span-2", 1000);
        $(this).removeClass("unview", 1000);
    });

    $(".grid-item").mouseout(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("span-2", 1000);
        $(this).addClass("unview", 1000);
    });
});
```

This is the js code.
If you are climbing through a mouse event, increase the image size by adding the span-2 class of the image.
If you leave, remove it and change it to the original size.

it's my code.
i make grid galley.
I want to develop my image when the mouse goes up.
but do it.

There will be a problem raising the mouse at the end.
how to solve??
please help me!

[codepen](https://codepen.io/hubeen/pen/WNGOmrm)

Answer (score 0):

You need to play with the mouse events in the JS file.  Here's one solution that could work for you:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".grid-item").mousedown(function () {
        $(this).addClass("span-2", 1000);
        $(this).removeClass("unview", 1000);
        $(this).focus();
    });

    $(".grid-item").mouseup(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("span-2", 1000);
        $(this).addClass("unview", 1000);
    });
});
```

But you can play around with the [mouse events](https://www.educba.com/javascript-mouse-events/) and come up with whichever works best for you.

Comment: Is it difficult to implement by raising the mouse? thanks you :)

Comment: $(".grid-item").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).addClass("span-2", 1000);
        $(this).removeClass("unview", 1000);
        $(this).focus();
    });

Comment: I edited the code so it will be large when you hold the mouse down and small when you let it up.

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: The bug's been fixed a little bit since we added code ("$(this).focuse()")

Comment: Okay, what still needs to be fixed?

Comment: I hope the last picture stays there without going down!

Comment: When do you want it to go up and when do you want it to go down?

Comment: I mean, the location of the photo.
0, 8 -> 1,1 (span-2)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand.

Comment: i'm sorry i'm bad english :(

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".grid-item").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("span-2", 1000);
        $(this).removeClass("unview", 1000);
        $(this).focus();
    });

    $(".grid-item").mouseout(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("span-2", 1000);
        $(this).addClass("unview", 1000);
    });
});

Try this.